# Is there a standard way to programatically get the DHCP table from a router/DHCP server?

Tags: wifi, snmp, dhcp

I work on a project with several WIFI routers. I need to programatically discover the DHCP clients (IP addresses) currently allocated by a router.

Since I have several routers, I would like to use SNMP.

Is there a standard, such as SNMP, MIB, or a combination of them that can be used to retrieve allocated DHCP clients?

Comment: You'll need to do some research. What is your hardware? e.g. Cisco has https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-3s/dhcp-xe-3s-book/dhcp-serv-mib.pdf

Comment: router: d-link dsr-500 ap d-link: dap2660. i did snmpwalk on both but did not see the info i was looking for. Also, in the cisco mibs u've attached i dont see a mib for the actual leased ip addresses. Could you please point me to it ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was not via snmp but via syslog. Both d-link: DAP2660 access point and d-link DSR-500 have basic efficient syslog support.

For DAP2660 the syslog server config is under status->log->log setting menu. Where one can state the syslog server ip address These syslogs will tell you which clients macs are connecting or disconnecting from the wifi

For DSR-500 syslog configuration is done in two stages: first configure the syslog server under Maintenance->Logs Settings->Remote Logging->Syslog. Then define which data will syslogged under several menu items under Maintenance->Logs Settings. One can determine various categories of events to syslog. among them dhcp messages and even http connections details.